# how to create snaps from copied yaml

Tags: snap

How do i create a snap from code copied from git-hub? I copied the yaml and this error appears. Do i need additional plugins??

```
W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found, E:Some index files failed to download.
They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Note that we can't be sure without seeing the yaml you copied.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `xenial` entry in http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/ for which snapcraft would fail since apt updating will not be entirely successful.

For your problems to go away, run:

```
add-apt-repository -r ppa:tualatrix
```